# Efficient array operations in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create a rather big array in python, filled with zeros and ones. In the end it should have around 1.2 billion entries. I do fill it like in the example. The idea behind is that 400 entries are a time slot and for each time slot there is a probability p that it is one. If that is the case, it is filled with ones for slot_duration time slots, otherwise it is filled with 400 entries, one time slot, of zeros.

```
import numpy as np

p = 0.01
slot_duration = 10
test_duration = 60
timeslots_left = test_duration * 1000 * 1000 / 20
transmission_array = []
while timeslots_left >= 0:
    rand_num = np.random.choice((0, 1), p=[1 - p, p])
    if rand_num == 1:
        for i in range(0, slot_duration):
            for j in range(0, 400):
                transmission_array.append(1)
        timeslots_left -= slot_duration
    else:
        for j in range(0, 400):
            transmission_array.append(0)
        timeslots_left -= 1
```

The performance is of course horrible. For a duration of 10 it takes around 45 seconds to generate the array, but it also takes 45 seconds just to iterate over it.

My question is, whether there is a more performant way to do it? Would it be better to initialise an array with fixed length containing zeros and then re-assign values to one? Or would that not help if iterating over it takes the same time?

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Based on my experience with APL, another interpretive language, for situations like this, it's better to create a large array and minimize the looping required to set the ones. Does your system have enough memory to handle such large arrays? What I don't know is what functions or operators Python has to help with your program.

Comment: I think that you have an error in the code. 
`timeslots_left - slot_duration` should be `timeslots_left -= slot_duration`

Comment: Also a general advice whenever you want to use less memory while generating sequences in for loops, it is better to use `xrange` because it evaluate lazily.

Comment: Once you have filled the array what are you going to do with the data? Depending on the use case you might just need to store every index where the value flips.

Comment: @saloua Thanks! I didn't see that. Maybe xrange might help. I will check it.

Comment: @niemmi That might work. I use it as input for Gnuradio, to generate noise time slot wise. Flipping might be enough. I will have a look at it, because it basically means 1, make noise, 0, be quiet.

Comment: @Patrick In this example you don't need neither `xrange` nor `range`. It was just a general advice. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have enough memory, you could replace that loop:

```
    for i in range(0, slot_duration):
        for j in range(0, 400):
            transmission_array.append(1)
```

by

```
transmission_array.extend([1]*400*slot_duration)
```

You perform 1 instruction, C-compiled, and you extend your list in 1 go, without all the resizing. Like this you're avoiding the double loop and perform a lot less resizes/memory copies under the hood.

And if `slot_duration` is constant, you could declare:

```
chunk = [1]*400*slot_duration
```

at startup so you can do `transmission_array.extend(chunk)`

so you're avoiding the allocation of `chunk` at each iteration

Same problem, same fix here:

```
    for j in range(0, 400):
        transmission_array.append(0)
```

becomes

```
    transmission_array.extend(zero_array)
```

with `zero_array = [0]*400`

Comment: That already makes it around 5 times faster, which is great! Memory might be an issue though, I reached around 9GB memory usage. But I think that should work. The machine it will run on has 12GB or 16GB. If you have any more suggestions, I'm open for them!

Comment: the memory shouldn't be an issue with a pre-allocated `chunk`. Another suggestion? upvote if it's useful :)

Comment: Well, the 9GB was with a pre-allocated chunk. ;) So I need to be careful. But I shouldn't get over that either way. On the other hand, the computation time is a bit over a minute, which has implications on what I want to do it with it. And it's already upvoted. ;)

Comment: thanks for the upvote. But `chunk` should be 4000 ones. (400*10) so no issue with the memory right?

Comment: 4000 or higher. The memory usage was for the whole program. But it seems it doesn't change when I use larger chunks. And the larger the chunk, the faster, which is good.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following more pythonic code.

It is better to avoid doing the loops in order to just append new values to the list.

```
p = 0.01
slot_duration = 10
test_duration = 60
timeslots_left = test_duration * 1000 * 1000 / 20
transmission_array = []
while timeslots_left >= 0:
    rand_num = np.random.choice((0, 1), p=[1 - p, p])
    duration = slot_duration if rand_num == 1 else 1
    transmission_array.extend([rand_num] * 400 * duration)
    timeslots_left -= duration
```

And as you are only storing zeros and ones in the array, I would suggest to use a [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). It is even less memory consuming.

Comment: Strangely enough, this is a bit slower then @Jean-François Fabre answer. Although only a few seconds. But it seems if I would introduce pre-allocated chunks, I will end up with his answer. Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Patrick It depends on what you want to do with the array. But it is worth trying to use the sparse array.
Upvote or accept the answer if useful :)

Comment: definitely more pythonic, although the factorization loses the possibility to pre-allocate the chunks, which is one of the major factors for the speedup. It's still the same dilemna between efficiency and readability.

Comment: Losing the possibility to pre-allocate is why I didn't choose that answer. For me the major point is speed up. The mention of sparse array brought me to the [bit array module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray), which already reduces memory usage immensely. I only need to convince my following application to accept it...